# How can I select all elements with the same class without selecting other elements with the aforementioned class plus a second one?

Tags: javascript, html, selectors-api

I'd like to select only spans that have a certain first class (price) without selecting similar spans that also have a second class (ishidden).

```
<div class="classbla classble classbli">
  <div class="classblo">
    <span class="price  ishidden ">
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried this:

```
var z = document.querySelectorAll('.price');
```

and this:

```
var z = document.querySelectorAll('.price span:not(.price.ishidden)');
```

and this:

```
var z = document.querySelectorAll('.price', 'span:not(.ishidden)');
```

and some more variants but without succeeding: it always selects all the elements starting with 'price' whether they have only the first class or both classes.

Also, I'm trying this on a site that isn't mine and using the navigator console.

Answer (score 2):

try `document.querySelectorAll('.price:not(.ishidden)')`

> As per https://developer.mozilla.org/
>
> As all CSS selector strings are valid, you can also negate selectors:
>
> var el = document.querySelector("div.user-panel:not(.main) input[name='login']");
>
> This will select an input with a parent div with the user-panel class but not the main class.

```js
var elem = document.querySelectorAll('.price:not(.ishidden)');
console.log(elem[0])
```

```html
<div class="classbla classble classbli">Test
  <div class="classblo">Test1
    <span class="price  ishidden">Test2
    </span>
    <span class="price">Test3
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me. It selects all elements with the class price and not ishidden

```
document.querySelectorAll('.price:not(.ishidden)')
```